# Is there any way to specify the MAX file size by type of file?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I would like to know how can I configure my *spring-boot server* to be able to assing **different max size values** for a file based on the **type of the file** that I want to upload.

For example, 10MB to .pdf files, 100MB to .mp4 files, 500MB to .zip files, etc...

For the moment I got this in my *application.properties*:

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=100MB
```

But it just assign 100MB for **every possible file**.

Any idea how I can implement it?

---

***Thanks for help!***

Comment: No, it's a standard Servlet 3.0 feature. The property simply sets the value on `javax.servlet.MultipartConfigElement`, as [**documented**](https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/#_tuning_file_upload_limits). The purpose is to prevent flooding the server to too large content, so if you need to support upload of 500MB for zip files, you need to set that as your max. If you want to restrict the size of files of different types when inserting into your database, that's something you'd need to validate yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your own multipart handler that lets you programatically set the max upload size. For instance, using [`ServletFileUpload`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/servlet/ServletFileUpload.html) in your controller:

```
DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory(thresholdBytes, tempDir);
ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
upload.setFileSizeMax(maxFileSize);

for (FileItem item : upload.parseRequest(request)) {
    // Save the file
    File uploadedFile = new File(myPath);
    item.write(uploadedFile);
}
```

For more control over the stream handling you can use `item.getInputStream()` and transfer the bytes using your own streaming logic.

To use this you'll need to either disable Spring's default mulitpart handling with `spring.servlet.multipart.enabled = false` or `spring.servlet.multipart.resolve-lazily = true`.

The second option is to register multiple servlets, each handling a different file type, and define a different `@MultipartConfig` (with `maxFileSize` and `maxRequestSize` specified) for each. Then do an *internal redirect* to the file type-specific servlet from your master servlet.